# C#, Debugging an HTTPHandler

Tags: c#, debugging, httphandler

I have an HTTP Handler that is the entry point for 90% of our app.  Basically it gets a request, process a lot of data and returns a very specific file depending on the client & web page it is embedded on, etc.  I have setup the **Application Mappings** so that all **.kab** extensions point to *C:\Windows...\aspnet_isapi.dll*.  I added my HttpHandler DLL to the BIN directory for my website.  When I try to browse to the test page the iFrame displays a 404.  **Did I miss something in my setup of the HttpHandler?**

As far as debugging my code, I’ve tried attaching but I keep getting a 404 error on the page and it never steps into my code.  **What is the best practice method for tying into the project in debug mode?**

---

Basic setup for test (all local on one machine):

- **IIS 5.1 on Windows XP Pro** – running a plain Jane default.aspx:

> <body>
>       <form id="form1" runat="server">
>           <iframe style="border-width: 2px; z-index:
>   100; overflow: hidden; width: 500px;
>   height: 423px;"
>   src="http://localhost/barrows.kab?client=33ee472yaaM24a">
>       </form>
>  </body>

- VS2005 running in attached mode to
  the INETINFO.EXE Process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to map .cab extension to your handler class in the web.config file.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bya7fh0a.aspx).

e.g.

```
<httpHandlers>
 <add verb="*" path="*.cab"
   type="My.Assembly,My.Assembly.Handler, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=whatever" 
   validate="false"/>
....
```

Comment: Ah - right.  Added the httpHandlers section and now I do not get a 404 error.  However, I cannot step into code to debug.  I copied my compiled DLL to the website BIN directory and in VS2005 Attached to the inetinfo.exe process, set a breakpoint in my ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) method and it does not break - at all.  Suggestions?

Comment: Perfect!  I added this to the top of my handler:
#if DEBUG
// This is here just for debugging in VS2005...
context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
context.Response.Write("In debug mode.  Debugger starting now...");
// To debug:
//  1) make sure the Build Type is set to Debug
//  2) build the project
//  3) copy the bin & pdb to the iis webroot\bin directory
//  4) set a break point below
//  5) Ctrl-Alt-P then select aspnet_wp.exe
//  6) Launch a web browser and navigate to http://localhost/default.aspx
//  7) Start debugging
#endif

Comment: I've normally done all this in a ASP.NET project, where starting the project under the debugger takes care of the details. VS gives various start up options, including launching a specific page or program.

Answer (score 1):

Go back to Application Mappings and make sure the checkbox for "Verify File Exists" is un-checked.  This will make anything with .kab be handled by .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Just one comment for the marked as correct answer; the type has to be specified the other way around, i.e. the handler first and then the assembly name (e.g.: type="My.Assembly.Handler, My.Assembly, ...")