# debugging a HTTP Handler

Tags: c#, debugging, iis, httphandler

I am using IIS 6 on 2003. I have created a HTTP handler dll that inherits from IHttpAsyncHandler. The dll builds into the inetpub\www8080root\common\bin directory. It is meant to intercept all requests.

The web site is set to monitor port 8080. I have created a common folder in the www8080root directory and have created a virtual directory in II6 to point to it.
I created a web.config file in the common directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" />
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*"
            type="x2Handler.x2Handler, x2Handler" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

When I access http://localhost:8080/common/index.html the HTTP handler causes a crash of w3wp.exe, when I look in the event logs I can see the error within the handler that caused the crash. When I set a breakpoint within VS 2005 the code it doesn't get hit.

In order to debug I need to somehow attach to the process when it is running under IIS but as soon as it processes a request, it crashes.

How do I debug a HTTP Handler dll under IIS? I can't see a aspnet_wp.exe process to attach to as described here: [C#, Debugging an HTTPHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070305/c-debugging-an-httphandler)

EDIT:
By adding Debugger.Break() I now receive the message "w3wp.exe has triggered a breakpoint" and it allows me to select a debug environment, but it loads without symbols

```
No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed.
```

I set Tools->Options->Debugging->Enable Just My Code
I set the path to the common/bin location to load symbols from. Any manually set breakpoints still display:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.
```

EDIT:
When it loads it appears to be looking for the symbols of ntdll.pdb. Even if I manually load the symbol file for the httpHandler it makes no difference.
The code is definitely executing though.

Comment: The symbols that it is referring to is a symbol database which is created when you build an app in "Debug" configuration in visual studio. The file extension is .pdb, make sure that is available to the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that .Net had been installed prior to the version IIS. I had noticed the "Edit configuration" button was disabled and found this site http://www.warfiblog.com/edit-configuration-disabled.
Following the instructions:

```
You will need to go to Start -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 -> Visual Studio Tools -> Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt. On the prompt write down this command:
aspnet_regiis -r
The above command will register dot net with IIS and now the button will also be enabled.
```

In doing that it fixed the debugging issue!

Answer (score 2):

Add `Debugger.Break()` a few lines before the exception occurs. This should give you a popup asking to attach a debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It did as you said it would, but I still can't debug.